# I am trying to manually update my out of date BIOS.. but cant seem to convert the .exe to .hdr

Tags: wine, 16.10, bios

I have an out of date bios and a no-longer-working ac adapter for my dell inspiron 5458. I am currently following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS#Using_WINE_to_extract_the_BIOS_image_for_a_Dell_Inspiron_1525).
Everything flows smoothly until I get to step:

```
wine 1525_A17.EXE  -writehdrfile -nopause
```

naturally I replace the file name with shit.exe (which I renamed my downloaded bios update .exe file, for ease of use)

and I continually get this error from wine:

```
___________________________________________________
BIOS Update Program

Error: Invalid Command Line.

Unrecognized command line option <-writehdrfile>.
The /? option will show command help.
__________________________________________________
```

I need to update the BIOS in hopes it fixes my adapter problem.

Comment: The instructions you link to are for a Dell Inspiron 1525, not for a Dell Inspiron 5458. That's why the instructions don't work.

Comment: I have looked up other instructions such as this "https://everlong.org/blog/index.php/post/2009/12/How-to-update-the-BIOS-firmware-on-a-Dell-Laptop-using-only-Debian-Linux"

...so you are telling me that a dell inspiron 1525 would have a -writehdrfile option??? that makes no sense. its just hardware.. im having a software problem.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what would happen with an Inspiron 1525, since you're not working with one. The error message you receive is quite clear: `Unrecognized command line option <-writehdrfile>.` The option won't work for you.

Comment: sure, but the magical question of the day is "Why won't this option work?" and I doubt my Inspiron model has anything to do with it. I appreciate your time though :)

Comment: The BIOS updater program for your model is different for the BiOS updater for other models. The one for your model doesn't have that option, as it's telling you.

Comment: When you start up your computer and press F12 repeatedly, does a boot menu come up? If so, does it offer an option to update the BIOS?

Comment: yes of course. but unfortunately due to my ac adapter issue, the flash update will not proceed due to: "inadequate power"

Comment: hence why I tried doing it through my ubuntu system manually :P

Comment: sorry for delayed response, had errands to run before dark.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell WINE that it should find the file in your current directory by using dot slash, (or put it in your C:\windows\system32\ WINE dir) :

```
wine ./1525_A17.EXE  -writehdrfile -nopause
```

Just tested it and does succcessfully produce a .hdr file.

Comment: hmmm, I tried what you suggested, but got the same output error

Comment: :~$ wine /home/peter/shit.exe -writehdrfile

fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x230000 0 0x22fda0 4
Unrecognized option: -writehdrfile

Comment: The error message shown in the question indicates that the `BIOS Update Program` is running, and Wine definitely doesn't produce that error message when it can't find a program.

Comment: hmmm, so it is my bios then? Interesting... so how would I be able to make a hdr file on this computer? I tried it on my desktop. same thing.

Comment: Please try : cd /home/peter ; wine ./shit.exe -writehdrfile -nopause